# color point shapefile based on cell values

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, colormap

I am using QGIS.

After exporting a point shapefile from a raster file, I like to know how can I color the point shapefile with a cell values.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the Style tab under layer properties.  Within the Style tab, change single symbol to categorized or graduated and choose which column you would like the color to be based on (cell value).  Then, choose your colors or color scheme.  Here is a resource that goes into depth about styling in QGIS: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html